# Text widget cannot read html tags Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Text widget in Flutter dose not support a special charterers like &, where sometimes this charterer comes like "first & second" from the database, or "&quot" should be ".

Text widget should read/convert these characters automatically. I have already fixed by following lines, But I need to put this solution in all Text widgets I have in my app.

**Is it possible to give all Text widgets the possibility to read these special charterers directly in main function in runAPP or "MaterialApp" without putting the following lines in all Text widgets the app has?**

```
      final document = parse(htmlString);
      final String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)   and try as follows:

```
Html(data: htmlString, style: {
              "body": Style(
                  fontSize: FontSize(18),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)
            }),
```

Comment: I know this plugin, but I need to change all Text widgets to Html, is there any solution to solve in main function or MaterialApp?